# How to fill the textblock with periods(Silverlight 5)

Tags: silverlight, textblock, fill, period, drawingbrush

I have a grid and three columns. Here goes the code:

```
<Grid x:Name="StaticGrid" 
        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
        VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
        Width="450" 
        Margin="3">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Description}" 
                Grid.Column="0" 
                Height="30" 
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
    <TextBlock Text="......................................................................................................" 
               Grid.Column="1"/>
    <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding ParamValue}" 
                Grid.Column="2" 
                Height="30" 
                HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
</Grid>
```

So if my grid has a fixed size then this solution is ok, but if it changes dynamically then I don't know how to change the periods dynamically.
I have read [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/62881f72-77e8-4fa2-a241-dbefea5b92a1/) post, but the solution given by ***Bob Bao*** is not working in `Silverlight`(I mean the `DrawingBrush` object is not supported).
I have also read [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26015/DrawingBrush-for-Silverlight-2-0) post, where ***Tamir Khason*** offers to clone the `WPF` object to use it in `Silverlight`. I don't want to use such complex solutions.
Does anyone have a better solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a path and play with [StrokeDashArray](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.windows.shapes.shape.strokedasharray.aspx) property like this :

```
<Grid Height="100" Width="100">
    <Path Data="M5,1 L1,1" 
          Height="1" 
          Stretch="UniformToFill" 
          Stroke="Black" 
          StrokeThickness="2" 
          VerticalAlignment="Top" 
          StrokeDashArray="1 1"/>
</Grid>
```

**Edit :** By playing with [LinearGradientBrush](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.windows.media.lineargradientbrush%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) properties and Height of rectangle (or other ui element)...  Change the `StartPoint` and `Height` for another dot size...

```
<Grid Height="100" Width="100">
    <Rectangle Height="2">
        <Rectangle.Fill>
            <LinearGradientBrush
                  EndPoint="0,0"
                  StartPoint="3,0"
                  MappingMode="Absolute"
                  SpreadMethod="Repeat">
                <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0.5"/>
                <GradientStop Offset="0.5"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Rectangle.Fill>
    </Rectangle>
</Grid>
```

Comment: A good solution, but different spaces fill differently. You will understand what I say, if you look [here](http://lms.bigbrain.am/jiwvT)

Comment: and here how it looks with the code I provided firstly:
[click here](http://lms.bigbrain.am/RosdX)

Comment: I had to correct the position with margin but this is a solution, thank you!